# Uniqueness of Fokker-Planck solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I am interested in the Fokker-Planck equation of the evolution of a probability distribution, which is described by

$$
\partial_t p(x,t) = \mathbf{\nabla}\cdot \big( \nabla E(x)\, p(x,t) + \nabla p(x,t) \big)
$$

This stochastic process has the steady-state $ p_{ss}(x) \propto e^{-E(x)}$. Note that the steady-state is any function $p$ satisfying
$$
\nabla^2E(x) \, p(x) + \nabla E(x) \cdot \nabla p(x) + \nabla^2 p(x) =0
$$
My question is, whether or not the steady-state is unique (up to a constant factor) when we impose periodic boundary (i.e., say $x\in [-1,1]^d$ and $E$ is periodic).

Comment: How do you define "periodic" when $x\in \Bbb R^d$?

Comment: Take $x \in [-1,1]^d$. Also let $E$ and all its derivatives be equal at the opposite boundaries.

Comment: Maybe look for a solution of the form 
$$p(x,t)=f(t)G(E(x))$$
I tried this but didnt get very far...

Comment: Is it possible to write the equation wrt $E(x)$ or $p(x)$ only?

Comment: What is assumed about $E$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no periodic steady state solutions except $p_{ss}(x) \propto e^{-E(x)}$.

Let $q(x) = e^{E(x)}p^\ast(x)$, where $p^\ast$ is any steady state solution. Then the steady state equation for $p^\ast$ becomes
$$
\nabla \cdot \left( e^{-E(x)} \nabla q(x)\right)= 0 \, .
$$
Your question now is whether there are non-constant periodic solutions of this equation.

Multiply the equation with $-q$, integrate over the domain of periodicity $D = [-1,1]^d$, and integrate by parts. Since all boundary terms cancel, the result is the identity
$$
\int_D e^{- E(x)} |\nabla q(x)|^2 \, dx = 0
$$

This is only possible if $\nabla q$ vanishes identically, i.e. if $q$ is constant.

The argument works if $E$ is smooth, e.g. $C^1$.